# How to lay front layer in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a page I am working on, because it is in process I used an "Under Construction" banner. Given this [link](http://jrgleason.github.io/CbusDroid/) can someone help me make the png come to the front?

Comment: If it's under construction, then don't put it online yet. You'll only irritate people who will click the link to see it. Please read [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/26669/26004) and [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/22963/26004).

Comment: Thanks #gronostaj but really this is just a test for working with stylus/bootstrap. I haven't given it a high level domain or anything so I feel safe. Besides if I make people mad I would be happy because that would mean there is a market :-)

Comment: BTW this from your link is great! http://www.splashnology.com/article/25-creative-coming-soon-pages/5265/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#myCarousel {z-index: 0;}
```

Also consider doing `position: fixed` to keep the sign in position during scrolling.

If you then want your slider controls to be accessible, you'll have to shrink `.UnderConstruction` and center it so it's not covering them.

Comment: No quite but close I think I am going to delete because I missed a z-index on carousel-caption that was causing this.

Comment: Huh, I will have to go back through and test but it seems to me that CSS gives precedent to the most specific styles. And since the z-index is set on the div further down not sure how this would propagate. Not to mention bad practice to style to an ID ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I missed a div w/ a z-index further down in my CSS. By fixing this to allow the banner in front it works. I did this by changing the z-index given the class. Although technically the first answer is correct as well, modern practices suggest to avoid id based styling.

It should also be noted that gronostaj is also correct that this sort of "Under Construction" could easily be swapped out for a contact us window.